# Совершенная раскраска графа (перебор с возвратом)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо сделать совершенную раскраску графа. "Раскраска вершин графа G называется совершенной, если для любых двух вершин одного цвета цветовые составы их окружения совпадают. В частности, это означает, что все соцветные вершины в G имеют одинаковую степень." Мне необходимо раскрасить кубический (из вершины исходит 3 ребра) граф в 2 цвета (белый и черный например). По имеющийся матрице параметров (например по матрице A):

```
A = [[1,2],[2,1]] 
A[i] - это цвет нашей обрабатываемой вершины (0-белый, 1-черный).
A[i][0] - это столько вершин белого цвета соседствует с вершиной i-цвета.
A[i][1] - это столько вершин черного цвета соседствует с вершиной i-цвета.
```

У меня есть готовый алгоритм с полным перебором всевозможных вариантов:

```
function colorGraph(){
    document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = '<p1> </p1>';
    var chosen_matrix = document.getElementById("matrix").value-1;
    var n = nodes.length; //Число вершин
    var edge_n = edges.length; //Число рёбер

    var Edges = edges.get({
        fields: ['from','to']
    }); //Получаем данные
    var Nodes = nodes.get({
        fields: ['id']
    }); //Получаем данные

    //Перекрашивание в дефолтный цвет
    for(var i = 0; i < n;i++){
            nodes.update([{id: Nodes[i].id , color:{background: 'lightblue'}}]);
    }

    var flag; //Флажок
    var w_amount; //Число белых вершин
    var b_amount; //Число черных вершин

    var color = [] //Массив цветов
    for(var i = 0;i<n;i++) color[Nodes[i].id] = 0;
    //Начало алгоритма
    do{ 
        //Прибавление единицы
        try{
            color[Nodes[0].id] += 1;
        }
        catch(err){
            document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = '<p1 style = "color: red">Создайте граф</p1>';
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < n-1;i++){
            if(color[Nodes[i].id] == 2) color[Nodes[i].id] = 0, color[Nodes[i+1].id] += 1;
            else break;
        }
        if(color[Nodes[n-1].id] == 2) break;
        flag = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < n;i++){
            w_amount = 0;
            b_amount = 0;
            for(var j = 0; j < edge_n;j++){
                if((Edges[j].from)==Nodes[i].id){
                    if(color[Edges[j].to] == 0) w_amount++;
                    else b_amount++;
                }
                else if((Edges[j].to)==Nodes[i].id){
                    if(color[Edges[j].from] == 0) w_amount++;
                    else b_amount++;
                }
            }
            if((w_amount != MATRIX[chosen_matrix][color[Nodes[i].id]][0])||(b_amount != MATRIX[chosen_matrix][color[Nodes[i].id]][1])){
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(flag);

    //Сам процесс покраски
    if((!flag)&&(n)){
        document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = '<p1 style="color: green">Раскраска совершенная</p>';
        for(var i = 0; i < n;i++){
            if(color[Nodes[i].id] == 1)
                nodes.update([{id: Nodes[i].id, color:{background: 'orange'}}]); //Надо исправить расскраску
        }
    }
    else document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = '<p1 style = "color: red">Раскраска невозможна</p1>';
}
```

В данном алгоритме я перебираю все возможные 2^n комбинаций(где n-число вершин) раскрасить граф, и для каждой раскраски проверяю каждую вершину на соответствие матрице параметров.
Такой способ естественно неэффективный.У меня сильное ощущение, что решить данную задачу можно перебором с возвратом, но совершенно в голову не приходит, как реализовать этот способ в данном случае (возможно придется использовать в массиве 3 случая: 0-вершина не окрашена, 1-окрашена белым, 2-окрашена черным)? В интернете этот метод перебора с возвратом расписан в очень "общих" чертах (на самом деле хорошо, так как универсален).